# Accessing JSON data from API response

Tags: php, json

I have a response data like,

```
$response_array= "{status: 'false',description: '5100|4567897845'}"
```

json validator says it is a valid JSON.

but when i  try to access status parameter

```
echo $response_array->status;
```

it outputs nothing.

How can i get status value ?

Comment: Please try to convert it in array using json_decode($response_array);

Comment: First, the response is not well formatted

Answer (score 2):

You have got bad quotes in your JSON string, try to edit string to this:

```
$response_array= '{"status": "false","description": "5100|4567897845"}';
```

Then you can use `json_decode()` function, like:

```
$response_array = json_decode('{"status": "false","description": "5100|4567897845"}');
echo $response_array->status;
```

Answer (score 0):

> for php return json value is a simple string you need to decode them
>   using `json_decode`

```
$response = json_decode($response_array);
```

> if it returns as an object you can access using `$response->status` or if it's an array then you can access like `$response['status']`

For it to be returned as an array, the second parameter in json_decode has to be set to true.

```
$response = json_decode($response_array, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use json_decode which is used to decode a JSON formatted string. Hence, it is always advisable for string elements in a JSON pair to be enclosed within double qoutes. Hence, please format the response array in said format. Then you could simple use json_decode and access respective Key Value Pair.

```
$response_array= '{"status": "false","description": "5100|4567897845"}';
$obj = json_decode( $response_array);

echo $obj->description;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how can i add double quote to each parameter of response ?

Comment: @NiraliJoshi you've to manually add double qoutes. According to JSON, all string must be surounded by double qoutes, otherwise, it might treat it as a variable and result in error.

Comment: @NiraliJoshi where are you getting the response from?

Comment: response is from i-tel switch api. they decline to accept that their response data is not in proper json format

Comment: @NiraliJoshi Try this code on the response before using json_decode ().                      $json = preg_replace('/([{,])(\s*)([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+?)\s*:/','$1"$3":',$json);

Comment: output =  {"status": 'false',"description": '5100|4567897845'}   , but passing above sting in json_decode() gives error : syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ')'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111388/discussion-between-b-v-raman-and-nirali-joshi).